# Java: override method on demand

Tags: java, overriding, anonymous-class

Am I able to override a method on demand? I have a class that extends JFrame and has a JPanel inside. I want to draw a circle in the JPanel but I don't want to have an own class for the JPanel (then I could override paintComponent). My idea was something like this:

```
public class KugelClient extends JFrame {
 public KugelClient() {
    super("KugelClient");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
      //overriding method here
      g.fillOval(...);
    }
  }
```

Is there anything in Java which makes it possible to do something like this (e.g. with lambda?) or do I have do create an own class for the panel?

Comment: Yes, it's called *anonymous class*. And from Java8 there are lambdas, too. Which interface/method do you want to implement on demand?

Comment: I want to override the paintComponent method inside the panel thus I'm able to draw a circle in it.

Comment: Aha, got it. In a second I'll post an asnwer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an **anonymous** subclass of `JPanel` with an overriden `paintComponent()` method. Something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    //overriding method here
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! What would it look like with a lambda?

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds.

Comment: Lambdas work only with the so called functional interfaces (i.e. interfaces with one abstract method). Which means that this cannot be represented as lambda.